# JAX-WS client without a WSDL document file

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, client, jax-ws

I am consuming a webservice soa, with netbeans (jax-ws) i use netbeans auto generate client, and all run fine, but i see that the wsdl is always downloading while the client is running.

In production i don't want expose the wsdl, and i am trying to modify the client for don't require wsdl, all my intends are wrong, i find this:

```
WebService_Service svc = new WebService_Service(
  null,
  new QName("http://www.example.com/ws", "WebService"));
WebService port = svc.getPort(WebService.class);
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
  .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
    "http://www.example.com/real_endpoint_url_goes_here");
```

but when the first line is executed i found this exception:

```
Message: El contenido no está permitido en el prólogo.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.wrapException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.nextElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.hasWSDLDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea to ignore wsdl?

Comment: finally i migrate the client to CXF, and all work fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i use the CXF libraries and i achieve use the Paul Vargas answer:

> Without a WSDL document file
>
> This solution requires the client generated.

```
QName qname = new QName("http://thenamespace", "FooService");
FooService service = new FooService(null, qname); // null for ignore WSDL
Foo port = service.getFooPort();
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
    .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
    "http://foo.com/soap/fooBean");

// Use the service
String result = port.doSomething(param);
```

Using standard jaw-ws, this solution don't work, CXF is necessary.

Answer (score 22):

There are several ways, of which I will tell you two:

1. #### Use a WSDL document file locally

   Save a copy of the WSDL document file and the schemma files to your project.

   ```
   ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   URL wsdlLocation = classloader.getResource("MyHelloService.wsdl");
   QName serviceName= new QName("http://test.com/", "MyHelloService");

   MyHelloService service = new MyHelloService(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
   service.sayHello("Test");
   ```

   You may [combine](https://github.com/lenardg/WSDLMerge) the WSDL document file with the schema files.
2. #### Without a WSDL document file

   This solution requires the client generated.

   ```
   QName qname = new QName("http://thenamespace", "FooService");
   FooService service = new FooService(null, qname); // null for ignore WSDL
   Foo port = service.getFooPort();
   BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
   bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
       .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
       "http://foo.com/soap/fooBean");

   // Use the service
   String result = port.doSomething(param);
   ```

Comment: Thaks for the answer i am trying to use the way number 2, but i have the exception to the first post (the question)

Comment: I tried to summarise this all up in a post here: https://medium.com/@nieldw/setting-the-target-endpoint-url-on-java-soap-web-service-clients-d5079da7816

Comment: I had a similar problem and wanted to combine this with Dispatch, which didn't work for Apache CXF in this case. What helped a lot was some old IBM docu: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxwsdynclient.html

Comment: I tried the 2nd solution but it doesn't ignore the wsdl. It attempts to use the wsdl from it's original location from which I generated the classes with wsimport. Ended up using the 1st solution and saving the wsdl in the source code

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this, too.

In my case, I had put a dummy wsdl without endpoint address inside my web app classpath. After that, I set a valid address at runtime, like this:

```
    String WSDL = "/config/ws/Main_default.wsdl";
    Main service = new Main(Main.class.getResource(WSDL), new QName(
            "http://www.example.com/", "Main"));
    MainWS port = service.getMainWSPort();

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
            "http://app.example.com/ws/services/main");

    Object result = port.someMethod("some param");
```

Comment: confirm that this solution works with jax-ws, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This exception happens while there is a parse error in your xml and there is something wrong at the specified row and column. Check your xml

Comment: Yes, i think that the exception ocurrs because i am pass null to service constructor and it try to download the wsdl and not find anything. but i don't know how force client to not download the wsdl

Comment: try using no arg constructor WebService_Service svc = new WebService_Service()

Comment: thaks for the answer, but in this case, default constructor call to wsdl because have inside one reference to it. i try to deleted the inside reference to wsdl, but the problem persist. it s not posible use client without wsdl?

Comment: Are you using cxf or axis?With cxf the mentioned method works

Comment: i am using the default libraries that comes with netbeans (jax-ws) i follow this tutorial: http://martcode.com/tipsGallery/Webservice-Client-2-min-using-Netbeans.php?id=42