# TLS certification. TLSParameters with CXF conduit

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf, conduit

I am trying to establish TLS connection. I read that in order to implement it I should initTLS params and set it to the conduit.

This is a generic method that called from consumer side in order to get JaxWs proxy. Could you please advise me What I am doing wrong?

```
 public static <T> T getSvc(String urlWsdl, Class<? extends Service> svcClass,
        Class<T> endpointCl) {

    Service service = null;
    try {
        final URL wsdl = new URL(urlWsdl);
        service = svcClass.getConstructor(URL.class).newInstance(wsdl);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}

    final T endPointInterface = service.getPort(endpointCl);

    initTls(ClientProxy.getClient(port));
    return endPointInterface;
}

private static void initTls(final Client client) {

    final HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    final TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();

    try {

        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("path", "password");
        final TrustManager[] myTrustStoreKeyManagers = getTrustManagers(trustStore);

        tlsClientParameters.setTrustManagers(myTrustStoreKeyManagers);
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Now I am failing with a exception occuring at line `(service = svcClass.getConstructor(URL.class).newInstance(wsdl);)`

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at .....
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.selity.service.v1.SelityService.<init>(SelityService.java:40)
    ... 31 more
    Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://somehost/SelitySvc?wsdl'.:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
```

Answer (score 0):

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

It means that the client **is not trusting on the certificate presented by the server when it is trying to download the WSDL file**. This operation is prior to the configuration of TLS in the CXF client

Alternatives:

1) **Point to a local wsdl file.**

```
File wsdlFile = new File(wsdlPath);
URL wsdl = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
```

2) **configure the truststore at JVM level**

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",pathToYourTruststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
```

Comment: It's failing before. here -service = svcClass.getConstructor(URL.class).newInstance(wsdl);

Comment: It is failing in that line, when tries to download the wsdl: `Problem parsing 'https://somehost/SelitySvc?wsdl'.`

Comment: Is there any other option to implement it?

Comment: You can **configure the JAX-WS client without a WSDL file**.   In this case you have to update the service class code generated by CXF using the guidelines of this answer (step 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19827446/6371459