# Start the application with jaxws:client even whenthe web service is unavailable

Tags: java, spring, cxf, jax-ws

I have an application with JAX-WS client.

```
<jaxws:client name="http://XXXXXX"
              wsdlLocation="YYYYY.wsdl"
              createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="ws-security.sts.client" value-ref="ZZZZZZZ" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

When the application is started during the webservice downtime, the spring context fails and the application doesn't start at all.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [XXXX]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://YYYYY.wsdl'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: YYYYY
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: YYYYY
```

How to configure the application in such a way that it starts and the spring config doesn't fail.
I understand that the web service client won't work as long as the web service is down.
I need the application to start and use the web service once it is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can put WSDL file to your classpath and locate it in wsdlLocation.

Like `wsdlLocation="yyyyy.wsdl"`

Or you can handle it programatically. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815145/jax-ws-client-without-a-wsdl-document-file)

Comment: "put WSDL file to your classpath" -> That's what I tried. But this don't help much as the WSDLs have imports that themselves have `schemaLocation`s that might be unavailable.